# How to create a WebDriver instance to a dataprovider @Test method

Tags: webdriver, testng

i am running a browser instance inside a @Test(dataprovider .. method. But i am unable to pass the driver instance to the Test method,

Here is my code, in the last statement i am getting a null point exception.

My question is, How do i pass the instance of driver into the test method

```
@Test (dataProviderClass=GetData.class)

public class createUserPageTest {

private WebDriver driver;
private String baseUrl;
private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
private MailCode openMail;

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() throws Exception {
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
baseUrl = “http://demo.mysite.com”;
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get(baseUrl + “/pageLink/Home.action”);
}
@Test(dataProvider=”RegisterUserStage1″)
public void NewUsrStage1(String name,String email,String password)
{
CreateUserPage createuser = PageFactory.initElements(driver, CreateUserPage.class);
createuser.CreateUserStage1(driver,name,email,password);
try {
openMail.testValidateEmail(driver);
——-
——-
```

The error message displayed is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at demoname.org.createUserPageTest.NewUsrStage1(createUserPageTest.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1203)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1128)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1036)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

My DataProvider name is as follows

```
@DataProvider(name="RegisterUserStage1")
    public static Object[][] getTestData() throws Exception
    {
        Object retObject[][]=getTableArray("src\\resource\\TestData.xls", 0, "NewUserStage1");
        return retObject;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a method named RegisterUserStage1 which returns the three parameters in object[][] format?

Comment: yes i do, i have updated the question, with my data provider method

Comment: the xls file have a table with name NewUserStage1 with 3 columns

Comment: Do you see the browser open when tests start?

Comment: browser opens, in the address bar i can see the URL after so much time the page is displayed.

Comment: Where is openMail being intialized? The NPE could be for that too..

Answer (score 0):

There where multiple issues with code.
As AJ rightly pointed out objects where initialized .